# Vue.js missing required prop

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm just starting with Vue.js so maybe i'm missing out on something obvious. To practice myself I tried to do a simple treeView component ( with a subcomponent 'treeViewItem' ). I only have 1 property on the treeView which is the list of items: `items`
Here's the treeView component:

```
@Component
export default class treeView extends Vue {
    @Prop({
        required: true
    })
    items!: treeViewItemOptions[];
}
```

And I initialized the 'Vue' like this :

```
let v = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    template: `
    <div>
        <tree-view :items="items" />
    </div>
    `,
    data: {
        items: treeViewItems
    }
});
```

I'm getting this error: '[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "items"

I'm using typescript with `vue-property-decorator`
Also, I'm running `vue` 2.5.16 and `vue-property-decorator` 6.0.0

Thanks,

**Edit 1**
I tried replacing the `<treeViewItem>` with a simple `<li>` in the `treeView.vue` file:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <!-- it works if I replace the following <treeViewItem> for <li> -->
        <treeViewItem v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id" v-bind:item="item"></treeViewItem>
    </ul>
</template>
```

I did not get any error about the 'items' prop and I even saw a couple `<li>` generated in the html code so the `items` are working, just not when I'm using my `treeViewItem` component!

Here the other component :

```
@Component
export default class treeViewItem extends Vue {
    @Prop({
        required: true
    })
    item!: treeViewItemOptions[];    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to change data to a function? 
`data () {
  return {
    items: treeViewItems
  }
}`?

Comment: Check `treeViewItems` if it has data.

Comment: Are you sure `items!:` should not be `items:` instead?

Comment: @ittus yes I did tried a function, with the same result

Comment: @gypsyCoder yes it does, I only have a test program, the `treeViewItems` variable is initialized on the line just before the creation of the `Vue`

Comment: @Terry Yes it's for typescript, I need to put the '!' to tell typescript that someone else is gonna initialize this variable, anyway it won't compile if I don't put it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem, the subcomponent was importing the wrong ts file :

```
<script lang="ts">
    import treeViewItem from './treeView';
    export default treeViewItem;
</script>
```

Instead of

```
<script lang="ts">
    import treeViewItem from './treeViewItem';
    export default treeViewItem;
</script>
```

Damn you, copy paste!